# HTML form data to JSON(php)

Tags: php, html, json

I am passing some data to mobile via api from server.For this I have made a html form,which does has combination of text boxes,labels, select boxes, etc.Now on button click I want to convert all form data to Json format.What is the possible way to do it.

Like for example,

```
<label for="register_email">email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="register_email" />
<label for="register_password">password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="register_password" />
<label for="register_password_confirmation">password confirmation:</label>
<input type="password" name="register_password_confirmation" id="register_password_confirmation" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
```

So when user enters data,after a click the form data should be converted to the Json format.

Comment: give your form a id and then use `$("form_id").serializeArray()`

Answer (score 0):

In your other page...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    {
        $params[$k]=$v;
    }

    echo json_encode($params);
}
```

Comment: What’s the `foreach` for?

Comment: I could directly do the `json_encode` on POST , Seems like OP is new , so wanted to make it readable.

Comment: I’d rather say it’s unnecessarily confusing. This may make the impression, `json_encode` is a mutating function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_form').serialize()
```

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

use jquery serialize

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

`<form action="your_action_page.php" methd="POST">`

now check for the `$_POST` variable..

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $json = json_encode($_POST);
    echo $json;
}
```

Please let me know if you want any further guidance...